# How to make button appear at bottom of div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add an effect to a site. I have a list of icons that are arranged in 2 groups of 3, making a total of 6 squares using bootstrap's col-sm-4 with a set min-height.

What I am trying to do is when the user hovers over any part of the div, it changes the icon image, and makes the hidden button below visible.

I already have both of those features working, but to see the icon change you have to hover over the icon, and to see the button, you have to hover under where `<p>` tags are. I am looking for a way to make both of them change their state on a hover over their specific div.

Here is my code;

**html**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 info-item">
        <a href="#"><img src="../desktop/icon1.png" onmouseover="this.src='../desktop/icon1_red.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../desktop/icon1.png'"/>
          <hr>
          <div class="icon-text">
            <p>
               Increase your conversion rates, which will thereby increase profit and customer acquisition.
            </p>
          </div>
        </a>
         <div class="hidden-button">
          <a type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-transition">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-1x"></i>
            <span>Learn More</span>
          </a>
        </div> 
      </div>
```

**css**

```
.info {
    padding: 100px;
}

.info-item {
    min-height: 350px !important;
}

.info-item a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.info-item p {
    color: black !important;
}

#hidden-button i {
    color: red;
}

#hidden-button a {
    text-decoration: none !important; 
}



.btn-transition {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-color: #ef4035;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white !important;
    background-color: #e9241d;
}

.hidden-button a {
    visibility: hidden !important;
}

.hidden-button:hover a {
    visibility: visible !important; 
}
```

I am trying to do this without javascript, but if javascript is the only option, I would happily use js.

If anyone has accomplished something similar to this, I would love to hear about it! Thanks for the help.

Comment: `<div><a></a><p></p></div>` ==> `div:hover a, div:hover p{ ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
    <div class="col-sm-4 info-item">
      <a href="#"><img class="iconChange" src="desktop/icon1.png">
        <hr>
        <div class="icon-text">
          <p>
            Increase your conversion rates, which will thereby increase profit and customer acquisition.
          </p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="hidden-button">
        <a type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-transition">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-1x"></i>
          <span>Learn More</span>
        </a>
      </div> 
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
            .info {
                padding: 100px;
            }

            .info-item {
                min-height: 350px !important;
            }

            .info-item a {
                text-decoration: none !important;
            }

            .info-item p {
                color: black !important;
            }

            #hidden-button i {
                color: red;
            }

            #hidden-button a {
                text-decoration: none !important; 
            }



            .btn-transition {
                padding: 20px 10px;
                text-decoration: none;
                border-color: #ef4035;
                border-radius: 3px;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: 700;
                color: white !important;
                background-color: #e9241d;
            }

            .hidden-button{
                display:none;
            }
```

**Jquery**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
            $('.col-sm-4')
            .mouseenter(function(){
                $('.iconChange').attr('src', '/desktop/icon1_red.png')
                $('.hidden-button').show();
            })
            .mouseleave(function(){
                $('.iconChange').attr('src', '/desktop/icon1.png')
                $('.hidden-button').hide();
            });
        });
```

Not tested, but pretty sure this will do what you want.  Of course it will only work for a single button and icon set.  It will need more info to work with multiple div's, icons and hidden buttons.

Comment: Seems to work fine here.  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/joucej85/)  If you need it to work for multiple divs and different icons, you will need to add a variable for the icons and pass it to the function.

Comment: you're right. That was a typo on my end. Thanks for the help!